# Replace multiple consecutive hyphens in R

Tags: r

I have a string which looks like this:

```
something-------another--thing
```

I want to replace the multiple dashes with a single one.

So the expected output would be:

```
something-another-thing
```

Answer (score 2):

We can try using `sub` here:

```
x <- "something-------another--thing"
gsub("-{2,}", "-", x)

[1] "something-another-thing"
```

More generally, if we want to replace any sequence of two or more of the same character with just the single character, then use this version:

```
x <- "something-------another--thing"
gsub("(.)\\1+", "\\1", x)
```

The second pattern could use an explanation:

```
(.)   match AND capture any single letter
\\1+  then match the same letter, at least one or possibly more times
```

Then, we replace with just the single captured letter.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it with gsub and using regex.

```
> text='something-------another--thing'
> gsub('-{2,}','-',text)
[1] "something-another-thing"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
t2 <- "something-------another--thing"
library(stringr)
str_replace_all(t2, pattern = "-+", replacement = "-")
```

which gives:

```
[1] "something-another-thing"
```

If you're searching for the right regex to search for a string, you can test it out here https://regexr.com/

In the above, you're just searching for a pattern that is a hyphen, so `pattern = "-"`, but we add the plus so that the search is 'greedy' and can include many hyphens, so we get `pattern = "-+"`